# c# graphics drawstring() listview to image

Tags: c#, mysql, c, listview, c#-4.0

Iam developing a invoice printing application for my client in c# and database is mysql  .Products are added to a listview items .I want to draw that list view to a image . I tried looping the listview items . But it's not working . The data from the listview is not showing line by line .

NB: productlist is the name of the listview

```
           int column = 2;   

           Bitmap bit = new Bitmap("D:\\jijo.jpg");
            Graphics cd = Graphics.FromImage(bit);

           for (int i = 0; i < productlist.Items.Count; i++)
            {

           cd.DrawString(productlist.Items[i].SubItems[column].Text, new Font("Arial", 19, FontStyle.Bold), SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, new Point(0, 0 ));

            }

            bit.Save("D:\\sijo.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: You shouldn't tag this as `C`, as this is clearly `C#`

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing the string over and over in the same location because of `new point(0,0)`. Try drawing the strings one below the other. For instance, you could replace `new Point(0,0)` with `new Point(0, 24 * i)`. You can experiment with various spacing between the strings.

Edit: Since you're drawing on a picture, I would use a pixel height instead of a regular height. For instance, you could replace your

```
new Font("Arial", 19, FontStyle.Bold)
```

with

```
new Font("Arial", 19, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

Thus, your drawString call would look like:

```
cd.DrawString(productlist.Items[i].SubItems[column].Text, 
  new Font("Arial", 19, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel), 
  SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, new Point(0, 24 * i));
```

Comment: i want a line break for each items

Comment: Drawing into a graphic object isn't the same as printing to the console or appending text to a textbox. You always have to specify exactly where you want the text to go, so you have to offset the text yourself accordingly.